# Xbee data messed up with 2 sensors communicating to master

Tags: xbee

I have an Xbee Master and slave set up as below (from Arduino website):

This way works great for 1-1 communication. I'm getting my serial data perfectly. However, when I had one more slave, the data is completely messed up. How exactly can I get data from both sensors? (I thought, the master xbee module would separate node data by new line but it seems to be mixing the bits itself.)

Master
[image]

Slave
[image]

Comment: What are the addresses of the two slaves?

Comment: MY ID is 0001 and 0002. Their DL ID points to the master

Comment: @Raaj so two sensors are using the same serial port? If so, I guess you need to establish some protocol between them so they don't send at the same time.